# Why has my jQuery + AJAX stopped working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX, so I suspect the issue is some typo I'm not seeing. It was working fine, but at some point during editing the hide() + show() methods stopped working (tested it in Firefox + Chrome). I've pored over it many times and can't see what's wrong.

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('p').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';

        $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);

        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }

        function showNewContent() {
                $('#content').show('normal');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

In my **index.html** page the following script includes are in the `<head>` section:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include jQuery **before** your `script.js`.

JavaScript code is executed synchronously. In your example, `$` is (or at least should be) `undefined`, and of course `undefined` has no jQuery like methods.

Also, one of your callbacks is defined as `showNewContent()`. The parenthesis at the end will call that function and pass its results back as the callback, which is not what you want in this circumstance.

Instead, drop the `()` to pass just the reference to the function.

Comment: I think what you're saying is he should write his 2 call backs (showNewContent and loadContent) as references to functions in the form var loadContent = function(){...}

Comment: @ehudokai Not necessarily, just the name should do it, and the OP can leave them as declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your index.html stuff to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

and your code in script.js to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('p').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  })

  $('#nav li a').click(function(){
    var toLoad, loadContent, showNewContent; //keep the variable scope local
    toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';


    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);

    loadContent = function() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)
    }

    showNewContent = function() {
            $('#content').show('normal');
    }
    return false;
  });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works perfectly now! I do have a follow up question on the meaning of line you added: var toLoad, loadContent, showNewContent. Does this line mean that toLoad will be local to the functions loadContent and showNewContent. Isn't this the syntax you would use to declare three uninitialized variables with the names toLoad, loadContent, and showNewContent?

Comment: @dmoench yep, that line is simply initializing 3 variables, using var which keeps them local in scope to your click callback function.  Best practice says to initialize all variables at once.